# TextView added dynamically is not visible but hides other elements

Tags: android, android-layout, layout

I have a problem with adding `TextView`s to Layout. Some where displayed others not??
Here my code to generate the `TextView`

```
tv = new TextView(c);
tv.setLayoutParams(lp);
findAndSetAttributes(tv);
tv.setTextSize(22);
tv.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
if(!isEmpty());
tv.setText(getObjectsContent());
v = tv;
return v;
```

If I parse this XML FIle only the the first `TextView` is shown the other own not, but it seems that the `TextView` is added to the layout but not visible? I tried to `setVisibility` but nothing happens.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="128dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="57dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/linearLayout1"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="22dp"
            android:ems="10" >

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>

        <!-- this TextView is displayed?? -->
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/editText1"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText1"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="21dp"
            android:text="TextView" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
            android:text="Large Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/linearLayout1"
            android:text="Button" />

        <SeekBar
            android:id="@+id/seekBar1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_marginTop="36dp" />

        <TextView>
        </TextView>
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**EDIT**
Here the activity that "draws" the views

```
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);     
    setContentView(R.layout.gui);

    layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linlayout);   




 //   setResult(RESULT_OK,newIntent);

}

public void drawGUI() {
    viewObjects = new View[MainActivity.xm.objects.size()];
    viewLayouts = new ViewGroup[MainActivity.xm.objects.size()];

    iterativAdd(layout,0);


}

public ViewGroup iterativAdd(ViewGroup root, int from) {
    guiObjects gobj;
    for(int i =from; i<MainActivity.xm.objects.size();i++) {
        gobj = new guiObjects(i);
        if(gobj.isLayout()) {
            layoutlist.add(MainActivity.xm.objects.get(i));
            root.addView(iterativAdd(gobj.makeLayout(this), i+1));
            break;
        }
        else {
            viewObjects[i] = gobj.makeObject(this);


            if(viewObjects[i]!= null) {
                root.addView(viewObjects[i]);
                Toast t = Toast.makeText(this, "Object added "+MainActivity.xm.objects.get(i), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                t.show();
                continue;
            }
        }
    } 
    return root;


}
```

My root Layout, to which i add the other Layouts is a LinearLayout i don't know if this is the correct choice for me. 
But I cant figure out why the Textview is invisible???

any ideas?

Comment: post your full activity code.

Comment: without the full activity code, it's hard for somebody to answer. You are using a relative layout and all depend into where the insert of textview.

Comment: If a TextView has no text set then it is pretty much invisible, try replacing the line `tv.setText(getObjectsContent());` to something that you know will always work such as `tv.setText("test");`

Comment: @Sam nope i tried this but the textview still not displayed... when I put fill_parent to the textView the other elments disapear, this show me that the textview is added to the layout but for some reasons is not visible? any suggestions?